# vscode reference between html css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, reference

i'm an ex atom editor user until microsoft stoped the project, now i'm using vscode which is totally different workspace and extremely painful to me, after installing some extensions the problem is not fixed:
1- how to set vscode to make it recognize the attributes and tags between html and css and js? i mean you link your css file in html, then you open your css and you try to writ an id "#contain", but it doesn't autocomplet it (which was a default fonctionality in atom)

2- even installing es6 syntax, vscode doesn't have the browser syntax like DOM: nextSibling etc...

3- in atom with ternjs, when i start a new project it used to ask me which extensions i would like to use in the project: unable browser syntax, nodejs modules, other things etc ... after selecting some checkboxes atom creates a new json file which contains the informations used in the project just like "package.json" in npm, so, when i only want to use html and css i don't need to unable all functionalities to release resources ... in vscode there is nothing similar, help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Oyj.png)

Comment: what is the added information of the image

Comment: search on google you will find some plugin those can solve your problem.